# Apple Payment Gateway

Tags: ios, iphone, payment-gateway

I need to make iphone application that use payment gateway (using visa ... etc).

Is that doable ? Does Apple accept that kind of app? or should Apple apps use in-app-purchase criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is perfectly acceptable to do.

There are several apps which do this. The first example that springs to mind is tickets for public transportation.

But you can't use it to replace in-app purchases for products in your app, and you can't use it to bypass the App Store structure to trick Apple out of their 30% for app sales. It has to be something which exists/has value outside the app.

Comment: Do you mean that if i want to use any payment gateway, then i need to make apple involved with its 30% share in any payment transaction ?

Comment: No. Apple only takes a 30% cut of IAP and app sales for which they provide the infrastructure. What I mean is that you can use a payment gateway to sell something like bus tickets, but you cant expect to get into the app store with an app that uses direct credit card purchases for the things that Apple intends to use IAP for. You can't send people activation codes for features in your app for example. That would have to be an IAP.

Comment: @Heiberg Just to clarify, if my app allows users to purchase, say, advice and tips on dating and relationships, the content of which delivered verbally over the phone, not within the app, can the app use a 3rd-party payment system to facilitate the transaction and bypass the 30% IPA fee?

Comment: I would say that's a grey area. That content would naturally belong inside the app. If you really want to pursue this you might want to ask Apple about it. Send an email to the app review team explaining what you plan to do. But personally I would use in-app purchases for that and give Apple their 30%. It will probably more than pay for itself. You get a significantly lowered purchase barrier and access to a huge number of people who trust Apple to deliver a safe service and have already gone through the trouble of entering their credit card.